# what happen inside curly bracket in golang

Tags: go

anyone know what happen to this code, i get it when copy code to build golang micro service

```
var logger log.Logger
{
    logger = log.NewLogfmtLogger(os.Stderr)
    logger = log.NewSyncLogger(logger)
    logger = log.With(logger,
        "service", "movie",
        "time:", log.DefaultTimestampUTC,
        "caller", log.DefaultCaller,
    )
}
```

my question is what happen to inside curly bracket ?

```
var number int 
{

   . . . . . . 

}
```

Comment: It's just defining lexical scope. In that particular example, it does exactly nothing, except provide visual grouping, since there are no scope-local symbols defined.

Comment: In other words, `{ X }` is exactly the same as `if true { X }`. It's often employed to re-use a variable name without colliding with other values or types.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Curly brackets on their own define lexical scope in Go. Meaning, whatever happens in that scope, stays in that scope. Variable declarations, calculations, etc.

That said, it can drag the scope in from outside. Meaning if you declare a variable, like `number` outside, then modify said number in the curly brackets, you will see it modified.

Here is a post to understand scope and blocks: https://medium.com/golangspec/scopes-in-go-a6042bb4298c